# get all user who progam Id exit in a to many relation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I have two Entity User and Student program . User Entity having programs relation with to many relation to Student Program Entity.programId is key in student program Entity. I want to fetch all user who has programID 1 and 2. I have all user in an array and want to apply filter in that array. For this I am using NSPredicate predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ANY programs.programId IN (1,2)"]; But

Getting following exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "((ANY programs.programId IN (
        1,
        2
    )))"'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x02b5b5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x028178b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
        2   Foundation                          0x01f2a2bc _qfqp2_performParsing + 9399
        3   Foundation                          0x01f27d9a +[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:arguments:] + 71
        4   Foundation                          0x01f27d4e +[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:] + 50
        5   iWISESuperAdmin                     0x0015c8b4 -[MemberProgramView searchBtnPressed:] + 644
```

Comment: Where is your question? Where is your code? This is just a badly formatted crash log. It looks like you have made a mistake in `predicateWithFormat:` but you need to include that in your question.

Comment: Hello Jrturton, I have two Entity User and Student program . User Entity having programs relation with to many relation to Student Program Entity.programId is key in student program Entity. I want to fetch all user who has programID 1 and 2. I have all user in an array and want to apple filter in that array. For this I am using NSPredicate predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ANY programs.programId IN (1,2)"];

Comment: There is an edit button below of your Q. Use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parentheses do not match in your predicate. And to compare with an array or set of values,
it is much less error-prone to use the `%@` expansion:

```
NSArray *wantedIds = @[@1, @2];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY programs.programId IN %@", wantedIds];
```